# How to test if an Integer is within a range while using a TextBox in C#

Tags: c#, validation, textbox, boolean, range

I'm building a Windows Form in C# and I'm trying to test whether the users input is between 1 and 7 (Representing the number of days in a week, that a movie can be rented). If the test returns false, then I want to output an error message.  I'm using a text box to get the users input. The problem is, I keep receiving this error when running the program :

> System.FormatException was unhandled
>
> HResult=-2146233033
>
> Message=Input string was not in a correct format.

Can somebody please, tell me what I am doing wrong.
Thank you in advance.

Here is the code I have written..

```
 private void nightsRentedTextBox_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Boolean inputBoolean = true;
      
        if (int.Parse(nightsRentedTextBox.Text) < 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter a number between 1 and 7", "INPUT ERROR",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            inputBoolean = false;
        }
```

Comment: to start with use TryParse().....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `TryParse` instead.

```
int nightsRented;
bool res = int.TryParse(nightsRentedTextBox.Text, out nightsRented);
if (res == false)
{
  // String is not a number.
}
```

or you can use it like

```
int nightsRented;
if (int.TryParse(nightsRentedTextBox.Text, out nightsRented);)
{
    if (nightsRented >= 1 || nightsRented <= 7)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter a number between 1 and 7", "INPUT ERROR",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        inputBoolean = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can use if (Enumerable.Range(1, 7).Contains(NumberOfNights)) too.

Comment: Happy to help. :) @CaseySmith